# Override user's accent color in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

Is there a one-liner way to override the user's accent color in UWP for my application? I've been searching for this but apparently one would have to create a dictionary with each variation of the user's accent color. What I would like to do is simply change it from whichever the user selected to another one from Window's default accent colors.

I'm building an application for a local business and it's more important to them to have their colors on the application instead of whichever the computer's configured to use. Luckly, their "accent" is a color very close to Window's yellow accent color, so changing the accent to be used in the application to that would be very helpful.

Comment: I'm confused about the "one-liner way" and "What I would like to do is simply change it from whichever the user selected to another one from Window's default accent colors". Can you show more details about it and your expected behavior?

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT a one-liner would be something that takes just a line to make, like `RequestedTheme="Light"`, which overrides the user's Theme (Dark/Light) prefference. Likewise, I'd like to know if there's anything as short as this to change the user's Accent Color for the application, something like `RequestedAccent="Yellow"` (which as far as I know doesn't exist), or `ApplicationSettings.Color = Color.Yellow`.

Comment: Currently there is no method can override accent color like you said, you can only change the accent color by using the method from this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/color#accent-color).

Answer (score 0):

What you’re looking for is the [ColorPaletteResources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.colorpaletteresources) API.
By using it, you can override any of the System color in your app, including the Accent color itself.
It requires Win 10 1809 or higher.

It seems, however, to be some bug in it: by some test I’ve already done in the past, it seems to be working only when used in XAML (or before the `InitializeComponent()` in a page constructor) and it works apparently only for the Accent.

But this API is the most straightforward way of overriding System colors, as for now.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware there is no one-liner, you'd need to override each as shown below:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Color x:Key="SystemAccentColor">#107C10</Color>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```